# Dynamic Copyright With NoScript

Tags: javascript

I already have the code for displaying a dynamic year for a copyright in javascript, however I am wondering if there is a need to also put a `<noscript>` tag, to display something for users who don't have javascript enabled, if so what is the "legal"/proper way to say content is copyrighted in the  tag where I don't have to update it each year?

Should the  say something like "Current Year" something like this or is that even acceptable?

Comment: Do you have a back end? PHP, .Net, etc.

Comment: Don't have "a dynamic year" at all. Copyright dates should reflect the year the content was created (or updated) not "now".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I use PHP: `<?php echo "&copy; Me 2010-".date("Y"); ?>`

If you must use JS for this, and need a noscript alternative, `2010-Current` would do just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately the site was built before I came to the company and they built it in html, given the pages have been around for a while I don't really want to change the extension which is why I am opting for the javascript instead of php

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick replies